# How to find out if an OpenSSL certificate was created by a certain private key?

Tags: bash, ssl-certificate, openssl, private-key

I have an OpenSSl certificate. I also need the private key. I was told it is located somewhere on the server, and true enough, I found multiple SSL key files.

Before I try them all by brute force: Is there a way I can find out on terminal if a private key was used to create the certificate?

Answer (score 9):

The classic reference for this is [this FAQ](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html#verify) in the online Apache docs.

In that document, an `md5` of the modulus is used because

> As the public exponent is usually 65537 and it's difficult to visually check that the long modulus numbers are the same, you can use the following approach

This gives:

```
$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in key.pem.decrypted | openssl md5
(stdin)= 9fxxfoobar558d9xx0045a89467d2bxx

$ openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in crt.pem | openssl md5
(stdin)= 9fxxfoobar558d9xx0045a89467d2bxx
```

I'm proposing the use of process substitution to avoid visual comparison of the modulus:

```
$ diff \ 
    <(openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in cert.pem) \
    <(openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in key.pem.decrypted)
```

If the output is empty, the private key matches the certificate.

This is just a more convenient way to compare the strings than the one in Andrew Schulman's answer, which is, of course, also valid.

Another reference [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56697/determine-if-private-key-belongs-to-certificate).

Comment: Are you saying that the comparison of the pub key is not enough or is it merely a more convenient way to compare the cert and the key?

Comment: By "*comparison of the pub key*", do you mean just comparing the two keys themselves?

Comment: The modulus is the important part of the public key. So comparing just the modulus should give you the same result as comparing the entire public key.

Answer (score 7):

To check that a certificate file certifies the public key associated with a given private key file, compare the public keys associated with each:

```
openssl rsa -in KEYFILE -pubout
openssl x509 -in CERTFILE -pubkey -noout
```

The certificate and private key are matched if and only if the public keys are identical.